# How do I make egit respect multi-project git repository?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have a git repository that contains more than one eclipse project.  Its easy enough to import the eclipse projects, but I can't figure out how to get them to work with the eGit plug-in.

The tree output below shows the essentials of the directory structure I'm looking at.

```
bash-3.2$ tree -a
.
|-- .git
    ...
|-- .gitignore
|-- apps
|   `-- example-app
|       |-- .classpath
|       |-- .project
    ...
|-- cs-build.xml
 `-- services
     `-- example-app-service
         |-- .classpath
         |-- .project
         ...
```

How can I work with these 2 projects AND have eclipse recognize that they are from the same git repository?

Comment: I would just like to take a second to say: I think the real solution to this problem is to not use Egit. All of the experience I've had with it, and all the experience everyone I know has had with it has been bad. It messes up your repos. Commits show up in Egit but not in github, or vice versa. I knew a few people doing a project using Egit and recloning the whole repo became a regular weekly task because it would get so messed up. I implore you to just use the command line-- and it will solve this problem, too.

Comment: I have not had the same experience.  EGit works great for me and provides visual feedback directly as to the status of my working directory relative to the repository.  I have just not been able to overcome the issue that one "Eclipse Project = one Git repository".  I am in search of this solution.

Comment: Where are you having difficulty?  Importing them from the *Git* *Repositories* view usually works fine.  The only time I've seen it mess up were with extra .project files sprinkled around above the actual projects.

Comment: It looks like both projects have the same name (example-app)? This is not possible in Eclipse in general, projects share one namespace and thus must have different names. For EGit, having multiple projects in one repository is no problem (the EGit repository itself is like this).

Comment: My bad, the tree output was incorrect, the client app is called "example-app", the server app is called "example-app-service".  The problem is that eclipse imports the projects fine, but does not know that they are in a Git repository...forcing me to work with Git from the command line and denying me eGit feed back that allows me to conveniently work with the repository.

Comment: Hmmm.  This guy suggests it may be possible:  http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#tutorial_multiprojects but I have yet to figure out exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AHA!  I have figured it out!  The key is to Import the Project(s) in eclipse after you have the repository itself established somewhere on the disk.  During the wizard, Eclipse find the Project(s) and links each of them up to the repository.  In my example above, my Eclipse Package Explorer now shows

```
example-app [example-app master]
example-app-service [example-app master]
```

The clue that gave me hope was the tutorial here:  http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#tutorial_multiprojects

The exact sequence of events was something like...

1. File, Import...
2. Git, Projects from Git, Next>
3. Local, Next>
4. Add..., Browse , Finish
5. Select repo from 4., Next>
6. Import existing projects, Next>
7. Check the checkboxes beside the projects you want and click Finish

I'm off the command line and back in eclipse complete with feedback as to the status of the repo up through the remotes.

I'm still not so sure its a great idea to keep multiple eclipse projectes in a single repo, but this isn't my repo, its just where I have to work.

Comment: "I'm still not so sure its a great idea to keep multiple eclipse projectes in a single repo." It depends ... if code changes span multiple projects (depending on how they are organized, this may occur more or less often; changes in cross-cutting concerns will definitely do that) you may be glad to have a single history to deal with. We used to have all our projects in a single subversion repo at least; now trying with git.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked great. But I hit another related problem, EGit isn't picking up my top level .gitignore file. So I'm seeing thousands of Unstaged Changes in my Git Staging view. It looks like you have a similar configuration with a top level .gitignore, is that working for you with EGit?